# Definition of topology induced by a metric clarification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Page 119 in Munkres Topology second edition:

[image]

Is the collection of all $\epsilon$-balls only centred at $x$ and we conclude that any $x \in X$ must be in $B(x,\epsilon)$ because $\epsilon$ can take any value greater than zero and hence contains all points of $X$?

Or does the collection of all $\epsilon$-balls not only consists of all $\epsilon$-balls centred at $x$ only, but also all $\epsilon$-balls centred at every other point $x \in X$ ?

I can see that in both interpretations, the definition qualifies as a basis for the metric topology, but which of them is actually meant in that context?

Comment: The definition is about the collection $\mathcal{B}=\{B(x,\epsilon)\mid x\in X, \epsilon>0\}$. So $x$ ranging over $X$ and $\epsilon$ ranging over the set of positive real numbers. This collection serves as base for a topology and this topology is the metric topology induced by $d$.

Comment: The proof makes it clear that the $x$ can vary: "the first condition is trivial as $x \in B(x,\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$", so we need all $x$ to occur as a possible centre, for this remark to make sense.

Comment: He also says "for all $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$", so it's quite explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base is $$\mathcal{B}=\{B(x,\varepsilon)\mid x \in X, \varepsilon>0\}$$ so both the centres $x$ and the positive radii can vary as much as you like. (Munkres does say "for all $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$" explicitly.)

This gives the topology induced by the metric: a set is open iff it is a union of open balls, or equivalently:

$$O \text{ open in } (X,d) \iff \forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B_d(x,r) \subseteq O$$

Comment: Munkres says, the collection of all ' $\epsilon$-balls ' **for** $ x \in X$ , he did not say **for all** $x \in X$ , which made me a little confused, but I get it now.

Comment: @khaled014z often "for $x$ in $X$" is short for "for *all* $x$ in $X$", otherwise one would say "for *some* $x$ in $X$".

Comment: @khaled014z: Regarding Brandsma's comment that included <<often "for $x$ in $X$" is short for "for *all* $x$ in $X$">>, I've pretty much have always (not just often) hated this convention, and if you ever see me using this convention, trust me, it was a careless oversight on my part (unless I'm quoting something where it's used).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Especially in definitions I'd personally use quantors explicitly or set notation, just to be extra clear.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Set notation imo is the easiest to see through.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi sorry, I also have a question to you. I came about some lecture notes on topology:
And there it is being stated that the induced metric reads as follows:
$\tau_d = \{ \emptyset\}\cup\{U\subseteq X: \text{U is the union of open balls in X}\}$
Why does he include the empty set here?

Comment: sorry i mean the topology induced by a metric